# Função "Procv" com pyspark

Tags: python, big-data, procv, spark

Sou iniciante e gostaria de saber se há algum código para correlacionar duas planilhas por meio de índice (`CAUSE_CODE`), igual um `PROCV` no Excel, porém em Pyspark.

```
%pyspark
        machine_A_grouped = machine_A.groupBy("CAUSE_CODE").sum("Time").sort("sum(Time)",ascending = False)
        machine_A_grouped.show()        

(output)

CAUSE_CODE  sum(Time)
  7041        41730
  7031        28076
  7010        11486
    10         3899
   ...         ...
```

Os códigos das causas estão descritos em outra tabela que carreguei em um df chamado `machine_cause` .

```
machine_cause.show()

(output)

CAUSE_CODE     Desc
  7031        Cause A
  7041        Cause B
  7010        Cause C
    10        Cause D
  ...          ...
```

Gostaria de um código para:

```
CAUSE_CODE  sum(Time)     Desc
  7041        41730     Cause B
  7031        28076     Cause A
  7010        11486     Cause C
    10         3899     Cause D
   ...         ...        ...
```

Comment: Lucas, boa noite! Consegue disponibilizar os datasets? Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Lucas,

isso é chamado de join e existem alguns tipos, como: Left join, right join, inner join, left outer join, right outer join, etc...

Cada tipo de join tem uma finalidade, sugiro uma breve leitura para se aprofundar melhor.

No seu caso seria algo do tipo

```
join_result = (
machine_A_grouped.join(machine_cause, on = ['CAUSE_CODE'], how = 'left')
)
```

depois você pode explorar o resultado usando

```
join_result.limit(10).show()
```